# Algebraic Number Subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

Prove that the algebraic numbers
A = {$x ∈ C|x\text{ is algebraic over }Q$}
form a subfield of C.

I'm not sure how to get started on this problem. I know what a subfield is but I don't know how to show that this group is one of C.

Any help would be great, thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you know about algebraic numbers? Do you know about algebraic field extensions?

Comment: Yes, I do. I know the basics of how they act in functions but that's about it.

Comment: Well, do you know that a field extension $E/F$ which is finitely generated by algebraic elements over $F$ is an algebraic extension? If you do then it is easy to prove what you need. If $\alpha,\beta\ne 0$ are algebraic over $F$ then $F(\alpha,\beta)/F$ is an algebraic extension. Since $\alpha+\beta,\alpha-\beta,\alpha\beta,\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ are elements in $F(\alpha,\beta)$ we conclude they are algebraic over $F$ as well. So the set of algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{C}$ which is closed under all four arithmetic operations, hence it is a subfield.

Comment: Oh i see! Thank you! If you would like to put that as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: Sure. I added an answer.

Comment: $c \in \Bbb{C}$ is algebraic over $\Bbb{Q}$ iff the ring $\Bbb{Q}[c]$ is a finite dimensional $\Bbb{Q}$-vector space.

If $a,b$ are algebraic then $\Bbb{Q}[a,b]$ is at most $[\Bbb{Q}[a]:\Bbb{Q}][\Bbb{Q}[b]:\Bbb{Q}]$ dimensional, thus any $c \in \Bbb{Q}[a,b]$ is algebraic. It remains to show $c^{-1} \in \Bbb{Q}[c]$ a consequence of the fact $1+c f(c)=0$ for some polynomial. @Mark

Comment: @reuns What do you mean by $\mathbb{Q}[c]$? By $F(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)$ I mean the smallest subfield of $E$ (when $E/F$ is a field extension) which contains $F$ and the elements $\alpha_1,...,.\alpha_n$.

Comment: @reuns Oh, ok then. I just prefer to work with fields here. $\alpha\in E$ is algebraic over $F$ if and only if $[F(\alpha):F]<\infty$, this is an important step in the proof of the theorem I used in my answer.

Comment: @reuns I never said it is obvious. Of course it requires a proof (though it isn't hard), I just assumed OP already knows the theorem I used.

Comment: The smallest ring containing $\Bbb{Q}$ and $c$, that is the ring of polynomials in $c$ with coefficients in $\Bbb{Q}$, for $c$ algebraic it is naturally isomorphic to $\Bbb{Q}[X]/(f(X))$ with $f$ its minimal polynomial. Well no with fields it is not obvious that $\Bbb{Q}(a,b)$ is at most $[\Bbb{Q}(a):\Bbb{Q}][\Bbb{Q}(b):\Bbb{Q}]$ dimensional. For the rings the claim **is** obvious. @mark

Comment: @reuns By the way, a minimal polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$ so the quotient $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(f(X))$ is a field anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a theorem is field theory which says that a field extension $E/F$ which is finitely generated by algebraic elements over $F$ is an algebraic extension. From here it is easy to show that algebraic elements are closed under the field operations. If $\alpha,\beta$ are algebraic elements over $F$ (suppose $\beta\ne 0$) then by the theorem $F(\alpha,\beta)/F$ is an algebraic extension. Since $\alpha+\beta,\alpha-\beta,\alpha\beta,\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$ are all elements in $F(\alpha,\beta)$ we conclude they are algebraic over $F$ as well.

So from here we get that the set of algebraic numbers over $\mathbb{Q}$ is a non-empty subset of $\mathbb{C}$ which is closed under all four arithmetic operations. Hence it is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$.